# How to prevent a span from altering the distance between its two neighboring spans?

Tags: html, css, horizontal-alignment

I've noticed that if I have

```html
<span>x</span><span class="foo"></span><span>y</span>
```

with

```css
.foo::after {
  display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  height: 1.2em;
  border: 3px solid;
  margin-right: -6px;
}
```

**depending on *which* letters `x` and `y` are**, it can happen that the middle empty `<span>` inflates the space between those two letters.

I guess it has to do with the features of the specific font (and I expect the monospace font to be unaffected by this, but I haven't tried yet, and I don't want a font-dependent solution), but my question is how do I prevent that?

The aim is that the empty `<span class="foo">` is there, visible, and doesn't ever increase (or decrease, fwiw) the space between the two adjacent `<span>`s.

---

Below is a snippet showing the problem. If you look carefully, you'll see that while the red and green texts are horizontally aligned, even though one is the whole word *rararara* and the other is a sequence of `<span>`s with the individual letters, the presence of the empty `<span>` between every 2 spans in the blue text increases the horizontal distance between those letters.

---

##### Important:

Upon putting a checkbox in place to help the reader see the difference, I've realized that the behavior is even weirder than I expected: initially the alignment is I described above; when I turn off the visibility of the relevant `<span class="foo" id="foo">`, the  issue disappears (expected); but when I turn it back on, the issue doesn't come back (unexpected)!

```css
body * {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.main {
  font-size: 10em;
}

.foo::after {
  display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  height: 1em;
  border: 3px solid;
  margin-right: -6px;
  width: 0;
}

.one {
  color: red;
}
.two {
  color: green;
  bottom: 1.35em;
}
.three {
  color: blue;
  bottom: 2.70em;
}
.one, .two, .three {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 50%;
}

label#lab {
  font-size: 1em;
}

input:checked ~ div span#foo {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="cb" name="toggle" value="" />
<label for="cb">toggle to see the effect</label>
<div class="main">
<div class="one">
rararara
</div>
<div class="two">
<span>r</span><span>a</span><span>r</span><span>a</span><span>r</span><span>a</span><span>r</span><span>a</span>
</div>
<div class="three">
<span>r</span><span class="foo" id="foo"></span><span>a</span><span class="foo" id="foo"></span><span>r</span><span class="foo" id="foo"></span><span class="foo" id="foo"></span><span>a</span><span class="foo" id="foo"></span><span>r</span><span class="foo" id="foo"></span><span>a</span><span class="foo" id="foo"></span><span>r</span><span class="foo" id="foo"></span><span>a</span>
</div>
```

Here's a GIF showing what I see. I start thinking that it might be a browser-specific issue.

[image]

---

I've found another example that triggers the behavior I described above (including the part under the **important** section) also **on Chromium**. Here it is:

```css
div {
  font-size: 10em;
}

.mid {
  position: relative;
}

input:checked + div > .mid::after {
  position: absolute;
  /*left: 3em;*/
  content: "";
  height: 1.2em;
  margin-bottom: -0.2em;
  border: 3px solid #999;
  border-color: magenta;
  margin-right: calc(-6px);
}

.r {
  background-color: cyan;
  opacity: 50%;
}

.comma {
  background-color: yellow;
  opacity: 50%;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" checked>
<div><span class="r">r</span><span class="mid"></span><span class="comma">,</span></div>
<div>r,</div>
```

Comment: Does it work if you try it with a monospaced font?

Comment: Also spacing on `inline-block` elements doesn't always work as expected. Try using `flexbox` on your container element so that each letter and pseudo element has a more exact box size. Then troubleshoot from there.

Comment: Man, maybe I'm blind, but the `a` occupies the space it should occupy - that's how it was created in this font. `<span class="foo"></span>` has no effect. Provide more specific explanations and examples where can see the problem!

Comment: @imhvost, maybe the zoomed detail I've added helps you see the difference? `<span class="foo"></span>` does have an effect. No doubt.

Comment: all three colors are perfectly vertically aligned with each other

Comment: @Sean, I've added a GIF.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the negative margin and add vertical-align: middle to span

```
.foo::after {
  display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  height: 1.2em;
  border: 3px solid;
  /* margin-right: -6px; */   /* Remove the negative margin */
}

span {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: I asked about _prevent_ing the effect. Your question doesn't help. Try making a snippet and see that the result is that the misalignment will affect also the other letters.

Comment: @partha when you answer please try to put a runnable snippet into the answer, and test that your suggested code works.  Several answers you have put up recently are not as complete as they could be.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a browser-specific effect/bug. I've filed a bug report [here](https://github.com/qutebrowser/qutebrowser/issues/7968).